# Program works only with {} symbols in .h file

Tags: c, split, header-files, code-splitting

I have three files.
Why program works only with {} symbols in .h file?

szereg.c:

```
    #include "szereg.h"

double szereg(double x, double eps, int *sw, int *M, int *stop){ 

    double s, w;
    int i = 2;
        s=x;
        w=x;
    do{ 
        if(*sw==*M){
            if(fabs(w)<=eps && *sw==*M)
                *stop =3;
            else
                *stop = 1;
            return s;
        }
        w=((-w*x)/i)*(i-1);
        s=s+w;
        *sw+=1;
        i++;
    } 
    while (fabs(w) >= eps); 

    *stop = 2;

    return s; 
}
```

szereg.h:

```
    double szereg(){};
```

main.c:

```
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <math.h>
        #include <stdlib.h>
        #include "szereg.h"

        FILE *fw; 
        extern double szereg(); 

        int main(){ 

            int lp, sw=1, M, stop = 0;
            double a, b, dx, x, y, eps, z; 
            char *stopwar = "";



            if((scanf("%lf %lf %d %lf %d", &a, &b, &lp, &eps, &M) != 5) || a<=-1 || b>1 || eps<0.0 || lp<1){ 
                printf("Blad danych\n"); 
                system("pause"); 
            exit(1); 
        } 

        if(!(fw = fopen("wyniki.txt", "w"))){ 
            printf("Blad otwarcia zbioru\n"); 
            exit(2); 
        } 

        dx=(b-a)/lp;

        for(x = a; x <= b + 0.5*dx; x += dx){ 
            y = szereg(x, eps, &sw, &M, &stop); 
            z = log(x+1); 

            sw=1;
        } 

        fclose(fw); 
        exit(0); 
        system("pause"); 
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Let me guess: Without the curly braces you're getting a linker error along the lines of an unresolved symbol.

Here's the thing, these two statements are *exactly* the same to the compiler:

```
extern double szereg();
double szereg(); // without {} is exactly the same as with extern
```

What it tells the compiler is, that there is a symbol `szereg` that belongs to a function that returns a double and takes an unspecified number of arguments. It however does not "glue" together the different compilations units.

What you have to do is compile each `.c` file separately to an object file, then link all the object files together in a final linking step. So far you're probably linking only the main object file and nothing else.